# How to change button image size when button is resized?

Tags: swift, layout, uibutton, uiimage

I'm trying to set the image size for a button to match the size of the button. To get the actual size of the button, I do this in the layoutSubviews() method. But I ran into the following problem.
Calling self.setImage(imagePerson, for: .normal) causes layoutSubviews() to be called again and recursion occurs.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    self.tintColor = .white
    self.backgroundColor = .lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
    
    let size = self.frame.height * 0.5
    let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: size)
    
    let imagePerson = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill",
                              withConfiguration: config)
    let imageSafary = UIImage(systemName: "safari",
                              withConfiguration: config)
    
    switch restorationIdentifier {
    case "1": self.setImage(imagePerson, for: .normal)
    case "2": self.setImage(imageSafary, for: .normal)
    default: break
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property to track the change in the size of the button.

Something like this:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        self.tintColor = .white
        self.backgroundColor = .lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    }
    
    // to track the size change 
    var curWidth: CGFloat = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // only do this if the size has changed
        if curWidth != bounds.width {
            curWidth = bounds.width
            
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2
            
            let size = self.frame.height * 0.5
            let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: size)
            
            let imagePerson = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill",
                                      withConfiguration: config)
            let imageSafary = UIImage(systemName: "safari",
                                      withConfiguration: config)
            
            switch restorationIdentifier {
            case "1": self.setImage(imagePerson, for: .normal)
            case "2": self.setImage(imageSafary, for: .normal)
            default: break
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I used this condition.
if image(for: .normal) != imagePerson {self.setImage(imagePerson, for: .normal)}
And it works.
But your way seems better to me. Thanks